# Не корректно отображается launch image в ios

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Мое приложение работает в landscape ориентации. Я добавляю изображения для отображения при загрузке (launch image), соответственно для landscape ориентации (960 на 640, 480 на 320).

Но при старте приложения изображение отображается не верно, оно сжимается и отображается как для портретной ориентации (т.е. как бы перевернуто за 90 градусов).

Вот фото http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=eb6eb90f15c42ee9bcb7dcfd1a2b75da  Подскажите как это исправить?

Comment: Кто-нибудь может помочь?

Comment: выставьте соответствующий  deployment target в targets -> summary(судя по симулятору - 6.1). Там же оставьте нажатой только ту ориентацию которая должна поддерживаться.

Comment: Вы про supported interfase orientation (там где 4 картинки с ориентациями)? если да, то там все уже давно правильно выставлено.  приложения работает корректно, вот только почему то картинка при загрузке не корректно отображается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я полагаю, что речь идёт про iPhone (судя по скрину).

Посмотрите внимательно [спецификацию разрешений для Launch image](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html):

Для iPhone, для Launch images, там указаны только портретные ориентации - исходя из этого, нужно рисовать портретную картинку с нарисованной в ней боком надписью вашего приложения.

Comment: Да Станислав. Я буквально 5 минут назад уже это понял. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

deployment target совпадает с указанным в симуляторе? Ориентация xib'а в IB совпадает c указанной в supported interface orientation? Если билдите для  6.0+ проверьте стоит ли галочка на use autolayout

Comment: Все я разобрался в чем дело. Боже xcode, что ты делаешь xcode, прекрати xcode. 960 на 640 - не нужно было изображения в landscape ориентации заливать,  даже если приложения работает в landscape ориентации, то все равно на launch image нужно изображения в портретной кидать. т.е. 640 на 960

Comment: ну разобрались и отлично)